# How to make a WCF interface utilize variables declared in a service

Tags: c#, service, interface, windows-services

I recently followed the MSDN tutorial [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx) In order to make a service with WCF. My concern now is how to access a variable declared in `CalculatorWindowService` From `CalculatorService` so that I can modify it's value for later use in `CalculatorWindowService` For example if in the methods for Add,Subtract,Divide, and Multiply if I Also wanted the results to be stored into the `List<double> DoubleList` declared in `CalculatorWindowService`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Configuration.Install;

namespace Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples
{
    // Define a service contract.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        double Add(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Subtract(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Divide(double n1, double n2);
    }

    // Implement the ICalculator service contract in a service class.
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        // Implement the ICalculator methods.
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 + n2;
            return result;
        }

        public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 - n2;
            return result;
        }

        public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 * n2;
            return result;
        }

        public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 / n2;
            return result;            
        }
    }

    public class CalculatorWindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        public List<double> DoubleList = new List<int>();
        public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
        public CalculatorWindowsService()
        {
            // Name the Windows Service
            ServiceName = "WCFWindowsServiceSample";
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new CalculatorWindowsService());
        }

        // Start the Windows service.
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
            }

            // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
            // provide the base address.
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService));

            // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
            // listening for messages.
            serviceHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
                serviceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }

    // Provide the ProjectInstaller class which allows 
    // the service to be installed by the Installutil.exe tool
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
    {
        private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
        private ServiceInstaller service;

        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            service = new ServiceInstaller();
            service.ServiceName = "WCFWindowsServiceSample";
            Installers.Add(process);
            Installers.Add(service);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [best way to access a windows service via GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133474/best-way-to-access-a-windows-service-via-gui)

Comment: You asked the exact same question yesterday. You need to use an IPC mechanism to communicate with the Service from your GUI. These two articles give you exactly what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx and http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

Comment: The question has been edited to explain what I need help understanding.

Comment: @DarthSheldon WCF and Windows services ARE two different things. Windows service is a Windows process, so is your GUI application. That said, you cannot communicate with two processes by just referencing them in Visual Studio. You need to use an Inter-Process Communication (IPC) mechanism to do that. WCF would be the best option in this case. And the fact that two processes cannot talk with each other directly is not limited to C#, it's an operating system rule, and is the same across all operating systems.

Comment: I understand that and am attempting using WCF, please see the updated question. specifically the WCF code

Comment: @Servy Question Edited to better differentiate between the two

Comment: @DarthSheldon Your WCF needs to expose itself as a host, and the client needs to create a channel factory to that host. Once the channel is created, the client makes a call to the `updateProfile()`. On the service side, in your `updateProfile()` implementation, you simply add the profile object to the list.

Comment: but how is the updateProfile() supposed to know about the List? that is the issue I'm having is that the list is unknown to the interface. The list is declared in the Windows service, not the WCF service. and that is the part I'm struggling to understand

Comment: Your service project is a class library. Add a reference to the Windows service and make the call.

Comment: I went through some of your examples, It looks like my lack of knowledge was a major issue with me getting this to work. I've edited the question to be much more structured and appropriate

Comment: @DarthSheldon You need to implement the WCF service inside your Windows service, so that your Windows service becomes the host. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really, I have a public ServiceHost serviceHost in my service, that's likely not what you mean though. why not show me in some code/pseudo-code as an answer

Comment: @DarthSheldon See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for your GUI (client) application to be able to talk to the Windows service, you need to use an Inter-Process Communication mechanism, since both the Windows service and the GUI are standalone, independent processes. The easiest way is to create a `NetNamedPipe` using `Windows Communication Foundation`.

**Part I: Windows Service**

I'm assuming you already have created a Windows service and know how to deploy it. So we begin by adding a contract to the Windows service project called `ICalculatorService` (make sure this interface is in its own file):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculatorService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Add(double value);

    [OperationContract]
    List<double> GetAllNumbers();
}
```

Then, we need to implement this interface. Create a new class (again, in its own file) called `CalculatorService`:

```
public class CalculatorService: ICalculatorService
{
    private static List<double> m_myValues = new List<double>();

    public void Add(double value)
    {
        m_myValues.Add(value);
    }

    public List<double> GetAllNumbers()
    {
        return m_myValues;
    }
}
```

Notice that we have a `static List<double>` which holds all the values. Now, we need make the Windows service a host, so that the client (GUI) can connect to it. The code-behind for the Windows service looks like this:

```
partial class CalculatorWindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceHost m_host;

    public CalculatorWindowsService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // If the host is still open, close it first.
        if (m_host != null)
        {
            m_host.Close();
        }

        // Create a new host
        m_host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost"));

        // Note: "MyServiceAddress" is an arbitrary name. You can change it to whatever you want.
        m_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculatorService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "MyServiceAddress");

        m_host.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // Close the host when the service stops
        if (m_host != null)
        {
            m_host.Close();
            m_host = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is all we need for the on the Windows service side.

**Part II: GUI (Client)**
First, we need to make sure we create a contract just like the one we created in the Windows service, so that the client can successfully make the service calls. To do this, simply copy the `ICalculatorService` interface to the the client application. Make sure you change the namespace so that it's consistent with other classes in the client. I created a simple `Windows Forms` program with two buttons: **Add Value** and **Get All Values**. The code behind for this form looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void AddValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService> facotry = new ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/MyServiceAddress")))
        {
            ICalculatorService proxy = facotry.CreateChannel();

            // Generate a random number to send to the service
            Random rand = new Random();
            var value = rand.Next(3, 20);

            // Send the random value to Windows service
            proxy.Add(value);
        }
    }

    private void GetAllValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService> facotry = new ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/MyServiceAddress")))
        {
            ICalculatorService proxy = facotry.CreateChannel();

            // Get all the numbers from the service
            var returnedResult = proxy.GetAllNumbers();

            // Display the values returned by the service
            MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", returnedResult));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a snapshot of my files in the Windows service and WinForms projects to help you see where things are:

[image]

**Edit**
You can change the `m_myValues` to `public`, and access it inside the `CalculatorWindowsService` class.

Comment: Excellent tutorial! a follow up question: will this List `m_myValues` exist even if the GUI is closed down? I was under the impression that the WCF service was a temporary class. In my case if the client adds to the list, the client needs to then be able to close and have that list accessible by the service on regular time intervals. BUT you did answer the initial question and rather in depth for that matter!

Comment: `m_myValues` resides in the `CalculatorService` class which is part of the Windows service, so as long as the service is running, the list is kept alive and remains accessible through any client. Closing a client doesn't shutdown the service.

Comment: thats just what I needed to hear!

Comment: @DarthSheldon If I remember correctly, your first question had a `Profile` object in it. Note that if you need to send a custom type (Profile) back and forth between the client and server, you need to add the `[DataContract]` attribute to the class definition and the `[DataMember]` attribute to its properties.

Comment: yes, That's exactly what I plan to do for the custom typed stuff.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to get to m_myValues from `CalculatorWindowsService`: make a List<> in `CalculatorWindowsService` and make a piping connection like in the client app, then call `GetAllNumbers()` to get the list and put in a list on the service. BUT I have that issue where in `CalculatorService` a compiler warning of "unreachable code detected" about the Add method accessing `m_myValues`...

Comment: @DarthSheldon You don't need to open another pipe between the CalculatorService and and CalculatorWindowsService. They're both part of the same project. Move `m_myValues` to CalculatorWindowsService (where you have the m_host variable) and change it from `private` to `internal`. Now in your Add or GetAllValues method, just reference that variable like this: `CalculatorWindowsService.m_myValues`.