# "unreachable code detected" when in a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, service, windows-services

This question is directly related to [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238509/how-to-make-a-wcf-interface-utilize-variables-declared-in-a-service/18242840?noredirect=1#comment26749116_18242840) but I figured because the subject matter is different I would start a new question for the current issue. I have a WCF service a service, and a GUI. The GUI passes an int to the WCF which is supposed to stow it into the `List<int> IntList`; then in the service I want to access the list. the issue is that when I attempt to add to the list in the WCF service I recieve a "Unreachable Code Detected" warning, and the adding line is completely skipped when I go debug through it. How can I get this list to be 'reachable' ?

below is the WCF code, the GUI call to the WCF, and the Service using the `List<>` from WCF:

WCF:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://CalcRAService")]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Add(int n1, int n2);
    [OperationContract]
    List<int> GetAllNumbers();
}

// Implement the ICalculator service contract in a service class.
public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
{
    public List<int> m_myValues = new List<int>();

    // Implement the ICalculator methods.
    public int Add(int n1,int n2)
    {
        int result = n1 + n2;
        return result;
        m_myValues.Add(result);
    }
    public List<int> GetAllNumbers()
    {
        return m_myValues;
    }
}
```

GUI:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ChannelFactory<ICalculator> factory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/MyServiceAddress")))
            {
                ICalculator proxy = factory.CreateChannel();                
                int trouble = proxy.Add((int)NUD.Value,(int)NUD.Value);
            }
        }
```

Service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (mHost != null)
    {
        mHost.Close();
    }
    mHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost"));
    mHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "MyServiceAddress");
    mHost.Open();
    using (ChannelFactory<ICalculator> factory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/MyServiceAddress")))
    {
        ICalculator proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        BigList.AddRange(proxy.GetAllNumbers());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have:

```
int result = n1 + n2;
return result; // <-- Return statement
m_myValues.Add(result); // <-- This code can never be reached!
```

Since `m_myValues.Add()` doesn't alter the state of `result` in any way, why not flip those lines:

```
int result = n1 + n2;
m_myValues.Add(result);
return result;
```

Comment: I am extremely dumb... of course the code cant be reached after a return statement!