# service not reloading config file

Tags: c#, service, config

I developed a windows service using Visual Studio 2012.
This service has a config file. When the application is build, the config file takes the name of the exe + .config.
If I install the service everything works, it means that the service uses the settings in the config file.
If I want to change a value in the config file and I restart the service, it does not read the new values, but it is still using the original values.

It looks like if the config file is copied in a different location when I install the service and the config file is not used anymore. Why? Where is the config file that service reads?

Answer (score 1):

If you use .NET settings which you create in Visual Studio, then they are saved under

```
c:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\{AppName}\
```

Comment: I checked and it is not there

Answer (score 0):

this should work as you describe. you just have to be sure that you modify the correct .config file.

To check where your app resides, open the windows task-manager, right-click your exe and click 'properties'. here you can see the folder you app is running

Comment: There is something wrong. I am sure that the config file that I am changing is correct because if I change the file and I stop, uninstall the service and I reinstall it, it uses the changed config file. The problem is that just a stop/start is not working.

Comment: look at this question (yours is a possible duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104992/windows-service-config-file