# Raspbian -.net core application won't reload configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, raspbian

**Issue:**

I am running a .net core application on a Raspberry PI. I am loading the configuration from a JSON file and storing in a class for reference in the application -  a hosted service in this case. If I start the application manually and then update the config file, the changes are reflected in the application. If however I set the application to launch automatically on boot and then modify the config file, the application does not use the updated config.

I have tried launching the application via an entry in rc.local and as a service using systemd. Again while the application launches and runs with either method, it does not pick up config changes.

**System Details:**

- .Net Core 2.1
- OS Build: Raspbian 4.14.52-v7+ #1123

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Register Hosted Services

            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MonitorService>();
            services.Configure<AppSettings (Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
            services.AddMvc();

        }
```

**Service Constructor**

```
public MonitorService(IOptionsMonitor<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {

        this.AppSettings = appSettings;
    }
```

**rc.local**

```
#!/bin/sh -e

sudo  /home/pi/App/MonitorApp &

exit 0
```

**MonitorApp.service**

```
   [Unit]
 Description=My Sample Service
 After=multi-user.target

 [Service]
 Type=idle
 ExecStart=/home/pi/App/MonitorApp
 User=pi

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You'll probably get better results with research over on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ (But it sounds like you need to implement a listener on the config file so that a continually running process knows when it has been updated so it can reload it.)

Comment: Hi - thanks I'll give that a go. ioptionsmonitor should (and does) pick up config changes successfully when I run in IIS or when I launch the application manually on the PI. The issue is solely with launching the app automatically on reboot.

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5104992/1531971 I wonder if this is a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved as per the following:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90292/raspbian-net-core-application-wont-reload-configuration/90456#90456

I had to add a WorkingDirectory entry to the service file e.g.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Sample Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/App/MonitorApp
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/App

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```